# Dependency Injection based on Symfony components [Abstract Controller]

Tags: php, symfony

I build an application based on the Symfony 4 components but not using the whole framework.

I have an entry point

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require APP_PATH.'/var/cache/app/AppContainer.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals(); 

$kernel = new Kernel(new AppContainer());
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

I use routing and services configure by YAML files.
My Kernel file is:

```
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

final class Kernel implements HttpKernelInterface{

    private $container;

    public function __construct(\AppContainer $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
        $routing = $this->container->get('routing');
        $context = new RequestContext();        
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $routing->setContext($context);

        $route = $routing->matchRequest($request);
        $request->attributes->replace($route);

        [$ctrl, $action] = explode('::', $route['_controller'], 2);
        return $this->container->get($ctrl)->{$action.'Action'}($request);
    }
}
```

I don't use Symfony bundle (because I don't need all services what are there).

My idea is to each controller extends AbstractController.
The abstract controller should include twig render method. It means that TwigEnv should be a push as a dependency on services.

In such case, I can't use `extends AbstactController` with dependencies.

I'd like to avoid use Symfony style and include all container to the controller. The container should be just in a kernel, to controllers are just services.

My question is. Does it possible to use `MyController extends AbstractController` and get dependencies from the abstract controller?

Something like in services.yaml

```
abstract:
    class: App\Web\Controller\AbstractController  
    arguments: ['@twig']
  twig:
    class: Twig_Environment
    arguments: ['@twig.loader',{cache: '../var/cache/app/'}]
```

and in controller `MyController extends AbstractController` make available twig service.

Thanks for the hints.

Comment: This is major guestimating on my part, I've never used Symfony before. I assume you need to inject whatever services/classes you're using into whatever controller you're gonna define too. It's not enough to inject them into the abstract controller since that can never be instantiated. And since most if not all DI containers use Reflection in one form or another you have to have a concrete implementation of an abstract class.

Comment: you could use a factory service to create the controllers, in the factory you inject the dependencys and pass them in the factory create function for the controller

Comment: @sietse85 thanks, it sounds like a good solution. Will try,

Comment: sure please check https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html as well ;)

Comment: @sietse85 What you think about https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html and `abstract:  true` it looks like a native solution for this issue.

Comment: I used parent services and it works. Only one problem is that I can't use _defaults for children. Such a problem is no problem.

Comment: that is a nice solution to your problem!